# Desctructuring discriminated union

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write code that will work with generic discriminated unions with `type` property.

Let's say that I have bunch of discriminated unions like:

```
interface IFoo {
  type: "foo";
  foo: number;
}

interface IBar {
  type: "bar";
  bar: number;
}

interface IBaz {
  type: "baz";
  baz: number;
}

type IObject = IFoo | IBar | IBaz;
```

The first task that I solved is determining possible values of type property:

```
declare let _object: IObject;
type ObjectType = typeof _object.type;
```

(btw is there a way to do the same without extra declare?)

I need to declare a generic type to be used like:

```
Case<IObject, "foo"> // = IFoo
Case<IObject, "bar"> // = IBar
```

so that I can declare:

```
function filter<Type extends ObjectType>(
    objects: IObject[], 
    type: Type,
): Case<IObject, type>[] {
  return objects.filter((o) => o.type == type);
}
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible

```
interface IFoo {
  type: "foo";
  foo: number;
}

interface IBar {
  type: "bar";
  bar: number;
}

interface IBaz {
  type: "baz";
  baz: number;
}

type IObject = IFoo | IBar | IBaz;

type TypeSwitch<N extends string, T extends { type: N }> =
       { [n in N]: T extends { type: n } ? T : never };

type Case<T extends { type: string }, N extends T['type']> =
       TypeSwitch<T['type'], T>[N];

type F = Case<IObject, "foo">; // = IFoo
type B = Case<IObject, "bar">; // = IBar
```

Also, you can refer to a type of a property using 'indexed type query' type operator (actually the same syntax as property access with `[]`, only it operates on types)

```
type ObjectType = IObject['type'];
```

Finally, using all the above in `filter` gives the type of filtered array elements as expected:

```
function filter<Type extends ObjectType>(
    objects: IObject[], 
    type: Type,
): Case<IObject, Type>[] {
  return objects.filter((o) => o.type == type);
}


let o: IObject[];
const a = filter(o, 'bar'); // inferred as const a: IBar[]
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot [] in filter return type. Fixed.

Comment: Oh, the actual use-case for conditional types. How exciting! Thanks a lot.